# How can I use Angular 2 with NetBeans?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, netbeans, angular

I have tried every tutorial I could find to try to make a HTML/JS project with Angular 2 working on NetBeans, but none have worked. Maybe is my npm that is bugged (search, for example, doesn't work).

The `node_modules` folder that is created with `npm install` is grey on NetBeans and have some errors in some files (I don't know if this is normal). Any `.js` I try to import from `node_modules` folder gives the error `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` / `Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined`.

Does anyone have any idea what could I be doing wrong? Or does anyone knows any tutorial that have the code to download so I can compare with what I'm doing and see what is the correct? Every tutorial I have found doesn't have any code to download, just some pieces of codes in the page for explanation.
Sory if this isn't a good question, but I have been trying to make this work since yesterday without success and I'm completely out of idea.

Answer (score 8):

First I recommend to upgrade to the last version of NodeJS and NPM, to minimize the errors in your node_modules folder

Install the Everlaw's Typescript plugin from https://github.com/Everlaw/nbts/releases  . If you are using Netbeans 8.1 I think you can install it directly from the Plugins installer. I'm using NetBeans 8.2 and there is no problems installing the plugin manually.

Then on NetBeans go to **Tools -> Options -> HTML/JS -> Node.js** and write the right Node and NPM Paths and Sources, I would recommend check-on the three check-boxes in that panel.

For a quick start try the QuickStart demo from the angular.io page, it is not necessary make any change in the package.json.
The first time I tried to debug an Angular 2 application I put the **index.html** file directly in the **project folder** in order to do not make any changes in the **index.html script sources** nor change the project files structure but you need to change some properties of the project:

- In the project window right click the project and select **properties**.
- In sources change the **Site Root Folder** using the Browse button and select the project folder (You can ignore the warning that appears).
- In Run select **Run As: Web Application**.
- I recommend select **Browser: Chrome with NetBeans Connector**
- Using the Browse button go to the project folder and select **index.html** as your **Start File**.
- Select **Web Server: Embedded Lightweight**.
- And finally in **Web Root** write /Your_Project_Folder

run **npm install** from NetBeans

Click the run button and your web application must open in chrome, if you edit your html or typescript files and save them you could see the changes in the browser in real time without re-debuggind your application and can use the Browser DOM window to explore your elements created from Angular 2.

You still see some errors in your files because NetBeans is not fully compatible with the HTML Angularized syntax. But it runs flawlessly.

You can also run the **start script** directly from Netbeans to run your project using lite-Server.

[Screenshot NetBeans - Angular 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4XXV.png)

Comment: But there is no angular syntax support for the HTML files as you can see in your attached file `<my-app> ` is highlighted as an error. My question is that there is any plugin which  could support the angular syntax in HTML files?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to install the angular cli: `npm install -g angular-cli@webpack`

Fore more infos regarding this tool, take a look here: https://cli.angular.io/

Then create a new Angular2 app with `ng new <app-name>`

This will create a complete and working Angular2 application in the current folder.

`cd <app-name>` and start the app with `ng serve`.

Check your new created app in your browser on `localhost:4200`.

If this works, you can try to get started with your NetBeans! :)

Comment: I just installed angular 2 using the cli quick start guide using this command `ng new my-app` but now I cannot find the source folder on windows can you tell me where it is located?

Comment: depends on where you executed that command. default folder if your start your command-line is your user-directory.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I am executing that command in a folder on my desktop but it creates the project in `users/muhammad/` I just got it now.

Comment: just up-voted your answer as you are sure its correct. :)